# Selenium web input item has no text value

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create a python dictionary from elements on a web page. The sleeps are in to allow my poor internet connection and the glacially slow website to catch up. So far I have

```
driver.get("https://my.crawley.gov.uk/en/service/check_my_bin_collection?accept=yes&consentMessageIds[]=24")
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it('fillform-frame-1'))

WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="PostcodeSearch"]')))
sleep(1)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("PostcodeSearch")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("RH10 7AB")
sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="Choose_Address"]')))
sleep(1)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("Choose_Address")
elem.send_keys("12")
sleep(5)
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("nextText")
elem.click()
sleep(3)

collection_dict = {}

collectiondetails = {"nextrubbish" : (driver.find_element_by_name("rubbishDateNext").getAttribute("value"))}
                                      
print(collectiondetails["nextrubbish"])
```

However I'm struggling to get a value for the rubbishDateNext result. Inspecting the element, it would appear it's not actually got a value and just a load of validation. Ideally, I'd like to have the dictionary value for nextrubbish print as Friday 26 June

How do I get this out and into Python?

Comment: What is returned by `driver.find_element_by_name("rubbishDateNext").getAttribute("value")`?

Comment: @AlexeyR. it returns `AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `(driver.find_element_by_name("rubbishDateNext").getAttribute("value"))`

use

`(driver.find_element_by_name("rubbishDateNext").get_attribute("value"))`